# Reindexing two lists / flattening indices

Tags: combinatorics

If I have two lists/indiced that run from -N to N, call them A and B.  How can I create a third index, C such that C goes from 0 to $(2N+1)^2-1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call $i = -N, -N + 1, \cdots, N$ the index of $A$, and $j = -N, -N + 1, \cdots, N$ the index of $B$. The index

$$ \bbox[5px,border:2px solid blue]
{
k = (i + N)(2N + 1) + (j + N)
}
$$

goes from $k = 0$ for $(i, j) = (-N, -N)$ to $k = 2N(2N + 1) + 2N = (2N + 1)^2 - 1$ for $(i, j) = (N, N)$